# What is "(), the Unit value"?

Tags: scala

My scalatest unit test fails with the following message:

```
<(), the Unit value> was not equal to object ...
```

What is the type and value of "the Unit value"?

Comment: maybe this can help : http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Unit

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The type is `Unit` and the only value this type can take is the literal `()`.

Comment: Thanks. If I would like to match a value with "the Unit value", what would be a value to match? I attempted `"the Unit value" must be(Unit)` but the match fails.

Comment: @HowardGuo Just use `()`.

Comment: Or use any other value like eg. `akka.Done`

Answer (score 5):

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Unit.html

"Unit is a subtype of scala.AnyVal. There is only one value of type Unit, (), and it is not represented by any object in the underlying runtime system. A method with return type Unit is analogous to a Java method which is declared void."

The unit value is returned from any expression that doesn't have any other return type, eg

```
> val q = 1 until 10 foreach (_+1) // arbitrary expression of type Unit is assigned to q
q: Unit = ()
```

When you define a function like this:

```
def foo(x: Int) { 
 ..
}
```

Scala expects Unit to be returned. It's equivalent to

```
def foo(x: Int): Unit = { .. }
```

In short: Unit is like void in Java or C++, except in Scala no expression literally "returns nothing." If an expression/function is of type Unit it represents something that returns nothing of any real interest. I assume somewhere in your unit test you have something that returns () when you were expecting it to return something of a different value; possibly you have written

```
def foo {
 ..
  val result = something
}
```

Instead of

```
def foo: SomethingType = {
  ..
  val result = something
  result
}
```